# Designing a relaxation oscillator using TL074

Tags: operational-amplifier, design, frequency, oscillator, ltspice

I've been trying to design a relaxation oscillator using a TL074 op-amp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpvB17.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For an ideal op-amp this should produce a square wave with frequency

$$ f = \frac{1}{2\ln(3)100\cdot 10^{-12}\cdot 200000} \approx  22.7kHz $$

When I run this on LTspice using TI's spice model I get a square wave with a 20.5kHz frequency.

My question is, how do I approach picking the correct capacitor/resistor values
when taking into account the real world characteristics of TL074 such that the circuit achieves a 22kHz frequency?

Comment: How accurate are your resistor and capacitor values, by the way?

Comment: I don't know if LTspice has a correct model of the TL074. If it doesn't, look at the maximum voltage swing that the chip can produce.

Comment: I guess the lower frequency is caused by non-symmetry of the output voltage. This problem can be avoided by connecting R2 to ground via some large cap (gut feeling: 10μF)

Comment: @MichaelKarcher This is interesting. What is the reason behind the asymmetry of the output voltage and how does the capacitor help in balancing it?

Comment: The [TL074 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slos080) shows a symmetric buffer stage, but the precising amplifier stage is asymmetric. This can cause the max positive output voltage to be different in magnitude from the max negative output voltage. The timing formula you gave is only exact if R2 is connected to the avg output voltage. A capacitor would slowly charge to that average voltage. But I vastly overestimated the effect of the potential asymmetry, see my comments on the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ideal opamp swings the output in zero time, the TL074 takes a finite time to slew, and this extra time is added to the period, resulting in a lower output frequency.

Unfortunately the amplifier doesn't specify an exact slew rate, only a typical, so any correction for this effect will not be exact. But a nominal correction will be better than nothing.

You could improve the slew rate a bit by increasing the input overdrive by putting a small capacitor in parallel with R3, that 100k resistor will charge up the input terminal quite slowly, wasting another fraction of a uS. You would want a time constant of only a few uS with 100k, only 10pF or so, as it should have settled by the end of the half cycle so the DC level is correct for triggering the other half cycle.

An ideal opamp also swings rail to rail, where the TL074 does not. This does not matter, as the output voltage drives both the RC time constant and the R2/R3 comparison voltage, so the exact output voltage cancels out.

Comment: Of course! I forgot to take the slew rate into account! Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Cancellation of the limited swing only works if the negative and the positive output have the same magnitude. Take the extreme case of +3V/0V as exaggregated example. The discharge would never complete.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher I'm inclined to treat your contribution seriously, as this site is filled with noobs trying to run 741s at 5v rail, which will have their outputs doing just what you say. However, I think we can agree that a tl074 with a 12v rail that doesn't get above mid rail is a broken or shorted tl074.

Comment: @Neil_UK of course a TL074 at +/-6V is able to get below 0V. That's why I said the example is exaggregated. The effect that one half of the cycle is slowed down and thr other half is sped up, with the slow-down being greater in magnitude than the speed up already happens at lower asymmetries, like +4.5/-4.0 V. The positive cycle from -2 to +2.25 at 4.5 V takes \$ln(2.889)RC$, the negative cycle takes $ln(3.125)RC$. The effect is in fact an increase of the period, but I overestimated the effect: These values just cause a \$0.1%\$ slow-down.